# Using the DL Sin [x] in the vicinity of x = 0, I want to calculate an approximate value for [Pi]

Tags: equation-solving

Using the DL Sin [x] in the vicinity of x = 0, I want to  calculate an approximate value for  [Pi] by finding the value that cancels this polynomial near x = 3.1. but I don't know what I should put in FindRoot, I tried that: FindRoot[Series[Sin[x],{x,0,10}]] but it doens't work. Thanx

Comment: What is a "DL"?

Comment: sorry  i wanted to say the Series and i put:  FindRoot[Series[Sin[x],{x,0,10}]==0,{...}]

Comment: To get the polynomial, use `ser = Normal[Series[..]]`.  Then `FindRoot[ser, {x, 3.1}]`.